# Как поместить стейт с объектом в массив при нажатии кнопки?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

```js
import React, { useState } from "react";

const initialValues = {
  title: "",
  page: "",
  linkrep: "",
  description: ""
};

const AddPost = () => {
  const [values, setValues] = useState(initialValues);
  const [results, setResults] = useState([]);

  const handleInputChange = (e) => {
    const { name, value } = e.target;

    setValues({
      ...values,
      [name]: value
    });
  };
  const AddItem = () => {
    if (values !== "") {
      setResults([...results, values]);
    }
  };

  return (
    <>
      <input
        value={values.title}
        onChange={handleInputChange}
        label="Tile"
        name="title"
      />

      <input
        value={values.page}
        onChange={handleInputChange}
        label="Page"
        name="page"
      />
      <input
        value={values.linkrep}
        onChange={handleInputChange}
        label="Link rep"
        name="linkrep"
      />
      <textarea
        value={values.description}
        onChange={handleInputChange}
        label="Description"
        name="description"
      />
      <button onClick={AddItem}>Click</button>
    </>
  );
};

export default AddPost;
```

Comment: Какой массив вы ожидаете? Значений? Ключей? Массив ключа и значения?

Comment: разобрался. но почему то console.log выводит массив два раза